# Electrical breaker dependency

Tags: oven

What you describe has been very helpful .  When I turn on the stove on one burner, not the other ones causes a breaker to trip that services my den.  The stove continues to operate, no loss of power.  About a month ago my electrician came out and swapped breakers and it trips only when I turn on the stove using the front left burner.  As soon as the coil starts to glow, it trips.

I always thought the stove had its own breaker .  I can’t figure out why the breaker for the den trips and not the stove.  At this point can I conclude it’s the igniter for the coil?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about a  gas stove? .... electric stoves do not have an igniter.

Comment: @jsotola But "coil" definitely means electric. I think it is confusion between "igniter" and "turning on" - which on gas are the same but on electric is *only* "turning on".

Comment: Does the breaker for the den have an Arc Fault Circuit Interrupter (AFCI)? If so, that may be overly sensitive to something going on with the switch on the stove.

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel, and does the breaker for the den have a TEST button on it?